# Fitting Generalized Nonlinear Model in R

Tags: r, nls, gnm

I want to fit the following Generalized Nonlinear Model: `Probit(G)=K+1/Sigma*(Temp-T0)*Time`. As naive model, I created `Probits(G)` by `qnorm(G)` and then fitted the `Nonlinear Model`. But I want to fit `Nonlinear Model` with `logit` link similar to `glm` function in `R`.

How can I fit such Generalized Nonlinear Model with `logit` link in `R`?

```
Data <-
  structure(list(Temp = c(23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L,
  27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L,
  35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), Time = c(144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 240L,
  264L, 288L, 312L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 240L, 72L, 96L,
  120L, 144L, 168L, 192L, 216L, 96L, 120L, 144L, 168L, 192L), G = c(15,
  25.5, 27, 28, 28.5, 39.5, 41.5, 43, 13, 21.5, 29.5, 30.5, 32.5,
  35, 13.5, 28, 32.5, 33.5, 35, 39.5, 42, 6.5, 30, 39.5, 57, 58.5
  )), .Names = c("Temp", "Time", "G"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
  -26L))

Data$GermRate <- 1/Data$Time
Data$Probits <- qnorm(p=Data$G/100) # Get Probits


fm1 <-
  nls(
      formula= Probits ~ K+1/Sigma*(Temp-T0)*Time
    , data=Data
    , start=list(K=1, Sigma=2, T0=2)
    #, algorithm= "port"
    )
fm1Summary <- summary(fm1)
fm1Coef <- summary(fm1)$coef
```

Comment: If you want a logit link, your responses should be between 0-1 but your `Probits` values contain negative values. `nls` doesn't have a link function property, you just need to include the transformation in the model formula itself (assuming you use a transformation that makes sense). Or maybe i'm misunderstanding what you mean by wanting to use a link function here. Can you more explicitly specify the model you want to fit in your question?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick for showing your interest in my problem. Actually the response variable is `Data$G/100` from which I created `Probits`. As a student of Statistics, I know that such `transformation` can be avoided by using `linking`.

Comment: Linking only works if the fitting algorithm allows for it. `nls` (nonlinear lesst squares) does not usually allow for this. Linking is usually associated with `glm`. And the response of your model in R is whatever is on the left of the `~` in your formula. Are you trying to do a `probit` or a `logit` link? It sounds like you may need more statistical advice rather than programming advice. If so, you may consider posting to [stats.se] instead.

Comment: you should be able to do the equivalent of linking by applying the inverse-link function on the RHS, something like `GermRate ~ pnorm(K+1/Sigma*(Temp-T0)*Time)` -- a first pass at this didn't work, but it's the direction I would go

Comment: I think you should wrap the RHS of your formula in `I`, like `Probits ~ I(K+1/Sigma*(Temp-T0)*Time)`. Otherwise it's going to try and parse it with formula syntax (interpereting `*` as an interaction) rather than with normal math syntax.

Comment: Also you should post what exactly is going wrong. Are you getting an error? Do your results make no sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fit this type of model using the [`gnm`](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gnm) package for generalized nonlinear models. It takes a bit of work, as `gnm` uses pre-defined functions of class `"nonlin"` to specify nonlinear terms in the model and the ones provided by the package are generally insufficient to specify an arbitrary nonlinear function. However it is possible to define a custom `"nonlin"` function to use with `gnm`.

In your model, `k`  is a linear parameter, so we only need to worry about the second term. This can be specified via the following `"nonlin"`function

```
customNonlin <- function(Temp, Time){
    list(predictors = list(sigma = 1, t0 = 1),
         variables = list(substitute(Temp), substitute(Time)),
         term = function(predLabels, varLabels) {
             sprintf("1/%s * (%s - %s) * %s",
                     predLabels[1], varLabels[1], 
                     predLabels[2], varLabels[2])
         })
}
class(customNonlin) <- "nonlin"
```

In the returned list,

- `predictors` specifies that `sigma` and `t0` are predictors with a single intercept term (i.e. are individual parameters).
- `variables` specifies that there are two variables, to be supplied by the user via the `Temp` and `Time` arguments.
- `term` specifies a function to create a deparsed mathematical expression of the term, given labels for the predictors and the variables.

More detail on `"nonlin"` functions can be found in Section 3.5 of the [gnm vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/vignettes/gnmOverview.pdf).

Now we can try fitting your model as follows

```
mod1 <- gnm(cbind(G, 100 - G) ~ customNonlin(Temp, Time), family = binomial, 
            data  = Data, start = c(1, 2, 2))
```

Note that, as in `glm`, an intercept is added to the formula by default, which here will represent `k`. Although the starting values are far from the solution, the `gnm` convergence criteria are met at this point, so the algorithm does not perform any iterations. In this case a better starting estimate of `sigma` is required for `gnm` to converge to something more sensible

```
mod2 <- gnm(cbind(G, 100 - G) ~ customNonlin(Temp, Time), family = binomial, 
            data  = Data, start = c(1, 2000, 2))

mod2

Call:
gnm(formula = cbind(G, 100 - G) ~ customNonlin(Temp, Time), family = binomial, 
    data = Data, start = c(1, 2000, 2))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        sigma           t0  
     -2.589     1915.602        8.815  

Deviance:            53.53157 
Pearson chi-squared: 49.91347 
Residual df:         23
```

Actually it *is* possible to specify this model using the `Mult` function provided by `gnm`, as long as you don't mind re-parameterising the model:

```
mod3 <- gnm(cbind(G, 100 - G) ~ Mult(1, 1 + offset(Temp), offset(Time)), 
            family = binomial, data  = Data,
            start = c(1, 1/2000, -2))

mod3

Call:

gnm(formula = cbind(G, 100 - G) ~ Mult(1, offset(Temp) + 1, offset(Time)), 
    family = binomial, data = Data, start = c(1, 1/2000, -2))

Coefficients:
                             (Intercept)  
                               -2.588874  
Mult(., 1 + offset(Temp), offset(Time)).  
                                0.000522  
Mult(1, . + offset(Temp), offset(Time)).  
                               -8.815152  

Deviance:            53.53157 
Pearson chi-squared: 49.91347 
Residual df:         23
```

**EDIT**

The function of the parameters is specified in the `term` component of the list returned by `customNonlin`, which you can see via

```
customNonlin(Temp, Time)$term(c("sigma", "t0"), c("Temp", "Time"))
"1/sigma * (Temp - t0) * Time"
```

So if you just want to change the functional form, you will need to modify the `term` function. If you want to add/remove parameters, you would also need to modify the list in the `predictors` component. Similarly if the new term requires you to add/remove variables, you would modify the `variables` component.

Comment: Thanks @HeatherTurner for your answer. I wonder where we are specifying the model terms. Wonder if the formula will change, then how the function `customNonlin` will change?

Comment: I've added some comments on this.

Comment: Can you put more light on `"1/%s * (%s - %s) * %s"` and explain more? Thanks

Comment: I've used `sprintf` to create the string, each `%s` is substituted by the values given in the call to `sprintf`. See `?sprintf` for more details. You don't have to use `sprintf`, for example you could use `paste` to create the string.

Comment: How would one remove the intercept using a custom `nonlin` function?

Comment: The call to the `nonlin` function is just treated as a term in the model - so you can add to the formula as in `glm`. Specifically to remove the intercept you can add `0` or `-1` to the model formula.

Comment: Please, could you please explain when to use gnm and when glm or nls? Let say I want to fit a logistic model.

Comment: glm is for modelling a response with a distribution from the exponential family (e.g. Gaussian, Binomial, Poisson) and linking the expected value to a linear predictor (where each term is of the form coef * variable). nls is for modelling a continuous, unbounded response with a nonlinear predictor (terms are nonlinear functions of parameters). gnm combines the two, i.e. is like a glm but allows nonlinear terms in the predictor. A logistic regression models a Binomial response with a logit link - so use glm or gnm depending on the predictor, see also Sec 2 of gnm vignette for glm enhancements.